# How to install official php7.2 patch?

Tags: magento, upgrade, magento-1.9, php-7, patch

I am using Magento 1.9.4.0. I try to install the PHP 7.2 support patch found [here](https://magento.com/tech-resources/download#download2240). I downloaded the version for 1.9.3.1 - 1.9.3.9.

I get:

```
$ patch -p0 < PATCH-1.9.3.1-1.9.3.9_PHP7-2018-09-13-08-01-43.2_v2
can't find file to patch at input line 5
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git a/app/Mage.php b/app/Mage.php
|index 532eaca..9928cfa 100644
|--- a/app/Mage.php
|+++ b/app/Mage.php
--------------------------
File to patch:
```

Do I even need this patch, or does Magento 1.9.4.0 support PHP 7.2 out of the box?

I am using PHP 7.2.5

Comment: @Enigmativity, so you say that PHP and the patch utility has nothing to do with programming?

Comment: No, PHP quite clearly has something to do with programming. But your question, even though it relates to PHP, has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: It's like having a site where you can ask about driving and you come and ask how to change the tyre of your car. Cars are related to driving, but changing a tyre isn't driving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer [here](http://www.der-mage-experte.de/1478/magento-php-7-2-support-patch-installieren/).

The instructions on the official site are wrong, you have to use `patch –p1 < patch_file_name.patch` instead of `patch –p0 < patch_file_name.patch`

So I executed `patch –p1 < PATCH-1.9.3.1-1.9.3.9_PHP7-2018-09-13-08-01-43.2_v2`

Then a few interactive questions showed up which I just answered with `n` because I had most of the patches already installed.

```
$ patch -p1 < PATCH-1.9.3.1-1.9.3.9_PHP7-2018-09-13-08-01-43.2_v2
patching file app/Mage.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 56 with fuzz 2 (offset 3 lines).
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Data.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] n
Apply anyway? [n] n
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Data.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Session.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] n
Apply anyway? [n] n
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Session.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] n
Apply anyway? [n] n
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] n
Apply anyway? [n] n
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer/Attribute/Source/Group.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] n
Apply anyway? [n] n
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer/Attribute/Source/Group.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer/Attribute/Source/Store.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] n
Apply anyway? [n] n
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer/Attribute/Source/Store.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer/Attribute/Source/Website.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] n
Apply anyway? [n] n
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer/Attribute/Source/Website.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Entity/Address/Attribute/Source/Country.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] n
Apply anyway? [n] n
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Entity/Address/Attribute/Source/Country.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Resource/Address/Attribute/Source/Country.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] n
Apply anyway? [n] n
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Resource/Address/Attribute/Source/Country.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Resource/Address/Attribute/Source/Region.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] n
Apply anyway? [n] n
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Resource/Address/Attribute/Source/Region.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Source/Store.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] n
Apply anyway? [n] n
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Source/Store.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Install/etc/install.xml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] n
Apply anyway? [n] n
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Install/etc/install.xml.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/config.xml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] n
Apply anyway? [n] n
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/config.xml.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Abstract.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] n
Apply anyway? [n] n
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Abstract.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/Model/Observer.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 102.
Hunk #2 FAILED at 125.
2 out of 2 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/Model/Observer.php.rej
patching file lib/Varien/Autoload.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] n
Apply anyway? [n] n
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file lib/Varien/Autoload.php.rej
patching file lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 519.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php.rej
patching file lib/Varien/Io/Sftp.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] n
Apply anyway? [n] n
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file lib/Varien/Io/Sftp.php.rej
The next patch would create the file lib/mcrypt_compat/mcrypt.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n] n
Apply anyway? [n] n
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
patching file lib/phpseclib/Crypt/AES.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] n
Apply anyway? [n] n
Skipping patch.
3 out of 3 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file lib/phpseclib/Crypt/AES.php.rej
The next patch would create the file lib/phpseclib/Crypt/Base.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n] n
Apply anyway? [n] n
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
The next patch would create the file lib/phpseclib/Crypt/Blowfish.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n] n
Apply anyway? [n] n
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
patching file lib/phpseclib/Crypt/DES.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] n
Apply anyway? [n] n
Skipping patch.
3 out of 3 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file lib/phpseclib/Crypt/DES.php.rej
patching file lib/phpseclib/Crypt/Hash.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] n
Apply anyway? [n] n
Skipping patch.
29 out of 29 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file lib/phpseclib/Crypt/Hash.php.rej
The next patch would create the file lib/phpseclib/Crypt/RC2.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n] n
Apply anyway? [n] n
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
patching file lib/phpseclib/Crypt/RC4.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] n
Apply anyway? [n] n
Skipping patch.
5 out of 5 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file lib/phpseclib/Crypt/RC4.php.rej
patching file lib/phpseclib/Crypt/RSA.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] n
Apply anyway? [n] n
Skipping patch.
101 out of 101 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file lib/phpseclib/Crypt/RSA.php.rej
patching file lib/phpseclib/Crypt/Random.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] n
Apply anyway? [n] n
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file lib/phpseclib/Crypt/Random.php.rej
patching file lib/phpseclib/Crypt/Rijndael.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] n
Apply anyway? [n] n
Skipping patch.
13 out of 13 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file lib/phpseclib/Crypt/Rijndael.php.rej
patching file lib/phpseclib/Crypt/TripleDES.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] n
Apply anyway? [n] n
Skipping patch.
5 out of 5 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file lib/phpseclib/Crypt/TripleDES.php.rej
The next patch would create the file lib/phpseclib/Crypt/Twofish.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n] n
Apply anyway? [n] n
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
The next patch would create the file lib/phpseclib/File/ANSI.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n] n
Apply anyway? [n] n
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
The next patch would create the file lib/phpseclib/File/ASN1.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n] n
Apply anyway? [n] n
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
The next patch would create the file lib/phpseclib/File/ASN1/Element.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n] n
Apply anyway? [n] n
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
The next patch would create the file lib/phpseclib/File/X509.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n] n
Apply anyway? [n] n
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
patching file lib/phpseclib/Math/BigInteger.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] n
Apply anyway? [n] n
Skipping patch.
143 out of 143 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file lib/phpseclib/Math/BigInteger.php.rej
The next patch would create the file lib/phpseclib/Net/SCP.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n] n
Apply anyway? [n] n
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
patching file lib/phpseclib/Net/SFTP.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] n
Apply anyway? [n] n
Skipping patch.
41 out of 41 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file lib/phpseclib/Net/SFTP.php.rej
The next patch would create the file lib/phpseclib/Net/SFTP/Stream.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n] n
Apply anyway? [n] n
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
patching file lib/phpseclib/Net/SSH1.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] n
Apply anyway? [n] n
Skipping patch.
35 out of 35 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file lib/phpseclib/Net/SSH1.php.rej
patching file lib/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] n
Apply anyway? [n] n
Skipping patch.
47 out of 47 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file lib/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php.rej
patching file lib/phpseclib/PHP/Compat/Function/array_fill.php
patching file lib/phpseclib/PHP/Compat/Function/bcpowmod.php
patching file lib/phpseclib/PHP/Compat/Function/str_split.php
The next patch would create the file lib/phpseclib/System/SSH/Agent.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n] n
Apply anyway? [n] n
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
The next patch would create the file lib/phpseclib/System/SSH/Agent/Identity.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n] n
Apply anyway? [n] n
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
The next patch would create the file lib/phpseclib/bootstrap.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n] n
Apply anyway? [n] n
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
The next patch would create the file lib/phpseclib/openssl.cnf,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n] n
Apply anyway? [n] n
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
```